# why isnt my downloaded image showing

Tags: javascript, canvas, html2canvas

I have a problem I have been trying to figure out and I cant seem to find the right answer. When I download the image I only get a black image with nothing in it why is that can someone please help me. I don't know what to do.Thank you.
 this is supposed to work on a div not just plain image

```js
  $(function() { 
    $("#save_image_locally").click(function() { 
        html2canvas($("#scream"), {
            onrendered: function(canvas) {
                theCanvas = canvas;


                canvas.toBlob(function(blob) {
                    saveAs(blob, "Dashboard.png"); 
                });
            }
        });
    });
});
```

```html
<p>Image to use:</p>
<img id="scream" width="220" height="277" src="http://c8.alamy.com/comp/D8MF25/red-rose-flower-detailed-imge-D8MF25.jpg" alt="The Scream">


<button id="save_image_locally">download img</button>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout/3.4.1/knockout-min.js"></script>
<script  
 src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1/jquery.min.js"></script><script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout/2.3.0/knockout-min.js"></script>
 <link rel="stylesheet"
href="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.9.2/themes/base/jquery-ui.css" />
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.9.2/jquery-ui.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet"
 href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
 <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/FileSaver.js/1.3.3/FileSaver.min.js"></script>
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
<link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Philosopher' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
<script src="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<script src="https://rawgit.com/niklasvh/html2canvas/master/dist/html2canvas.js"></script></script>
<script src="https://files.codepedia.info/uploads/iScripts/html2canvas.js"></script>
```

Comment: I get *Error: Permission denied to access property "document"* in the JavaScript console. Do you?

Comment: not when i host it online

Comment: it also needs to bne a DIV i am sorry

Comment: The image need to be on the same domain if you want to use it in a canva

Comment: or have CORS headers provided and an appropriate property on the image

Comment: Also tried using same domain image and I still get the same problem this was an example

Comment: Do you realize that you're loading too much js files? Like there are three jQuery files being loaded: `/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js` and `/1/jquery.min.js` and `/jquery-1.10.2.js` (even if it's different version). Same for knockout, which is loaded twice (only different version)

Comment: I did not realize that thank you for that